# running git command using java in android

Tags: java, android, linux, git

I am trying to run some linux command such as nodejs and git
inside my android app so user can directly run 
their nodejs project and clone repos using this app.

For now im able to run some basic commands
like aapt,ls,cat,cal and get outputs.

```
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,env,new File(..));
  InputStream o = p.getInputStream();
  InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
```

Some command like top make my app freeze when run it.
But i think im not going to use it.
Before this ive tried to run javac,java that i get from jdk
but i just get javac not found. Im not sure what is going on .
I have already run chmod to change permission.

When searching for answer on this site i found that they referred to the termux and android terminal 
emulator. I read the source code and i found they using this to build environment:

```
            public static String[] buildEnvironment(boolean failSafe, String cwd) {
                    new File(HOME).mkdirs();

                    if (cwd == null) cwd = HOME;

                    final String termEnv = "TERM=xterm-256color";
                    final String homeEnv = "HOME=" + HOME;
                    final String prefixEnv = "PREFIX=" + PREFIX;
                    final String androidRootEnv = "ANDROID_ROOT=" + System.getenv("ANDROID_ROOT");
                    final String androidDataEnv = "ANDROID_DATA=" + System.getenv("ANDROID_DATA");
                    // EXTERNAL_STORAGE is needed for /system/bin/am to work on at least
                    // Samsung S7 - see https://plus.google.com/110070148244138185604/posts/gp8Lk3aCGp3.
                    final String externalStorageEnv = "EXTERNAL_STORAGE=" + System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
                    if (failSafe) {
                        // Keep the default path so that system binaries can be used in the failsafe session.
                        final String pathEnv = "PATH=" +PREFIX+"/system/bin:"+ System.getenv("PATH");
                        return new String[]{termEnv, homeEnv, prefixEnv, androidRootEnv, androidDataEnv, pathEnv, externalStorageEnv};
                    } else {
                        final String ldEnv = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + PREFIX + "/lib";
                        final String langEnv = "LANG=en_US.UTF-8";
                        final String pathEnv = "PATH=" + PREFIX + "/bin:" + PREFIX+ "/bin/applets";
                        final String pwdEnv = "PWD=" + cwd;
                        final String tmpdirEnv = "TMPDIR=" + PREFIX+ "/tmp";

                        return new String[]{termEnv, homeEnv, prefixEnv, ldEnv, langEnv, pathEnv, pwdEnv, androidRootEnv, androidDataEnv, externalStorageEnv, tmpdirEnv};
                    }
                }
```

And i still get the same result not found.
i added my filesDir to the PATH variable like termux and ATE does.
here my filesDir :

```
        /data/data/com.test/
                           files/
                           lib/libjni.so
                           system/bin/
                                  javac
                                 /lib/libjavacrypto.so
```

So the problem is i cant run cmd file from my dir
I tried using sh:

```
        cd $PATH
        javac
```

but return the same not found

please help me. This project is meaningful for me.
Thank you.

Comment: would this help: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git status");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line="";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }`

Comment: try `/data/data/com.test/system/bin/javac -help`... while most likely, you would have to push it into `/system/bin`, in order to have it on `$PATH`. `echo $PATH` should show what the path actually is - and also, that `cd` is useless.

Comment: Hard to tell from your post ; is `javac` in your `.../system` dir or `.../system/bin` dir?

Comment: @Andy javac is in /data/data/com.test/system/bin/

Comment: @MartinZeitler same result command not found....and i added $PREFIX to $PATH already as you can see in buildEnvirontment() above.

Comment: `cd` would not understand a colon-separated list of directories - on my ubuntu it gives No such file or directory - just cd with absolute paths for testing purposes.